# SQL Batch Update error - New request is not allowed to start because it should come with valid transaction descriptor

Tags: sql, jdbc, batch-processing

I am running microsoft sql 2008 and jdbc driver 3.0 and am getting this error on a batch SQL update

"New request is not allowed to start because it should come with valid transaction descriptor"

To debug I've reduced the batch size down to just one statement, but it still errors. Here it is

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM StaffDetail WHERE PsnID = 'GC91') 
    UPDATE staffdetail 
    SET    psnid = 'GC91', 
           servicegroup = '41B001', 
           discipline = 'IT', 
           dob = '1967-09-28', 
           ghdstartdate = '2008-12-15', 
           yearsexperience = '11 to 20 years', 
           classification = 'Admin Officer 1' 
    WHERE  psnid = 'GC91' 
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO staffdetail 
                (psnid, 
                 servicegroup, 
                 discipline, 
                 dob, 
                 ghdstartdate, 
                 yearsexperience, 
                 classification) 
    VALUES      ('GC91', 
                 '41B001', 
                 'IT', 
                 '1967-09-28', 
                 '2008-12-15', 
                 '11 to 20 years', 
                 'Admin Officer 1')
```

Why does it error? I've googled this and only found references to a bug in SQL 2005 not 2008.

Is there any way I can change the connection string I use to connect or change the SQL statements I use in the batch to try and avoid this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) instead which removes the `IF` and `ELSE` which makes it really one statement

```
MERGE INTO staffdetail AS TARGET 
USING (VALUES ('GC91', 
      '41B001', 
      'IT', 
      '1967-09-28', 
      '2008-12-15', 
      '11 to 20 years', 
      'Admin Officer 1')) AS SOURCE (psnid, servicegroup, discipline, dob, 
      ghdstartdate, yearsexperience, classification) 
ON TARGET.psnid = SOURCE.psnid 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET servicegroup = SOURCE.servicegroup, 
             discipline = SOURCE.discipline, 
             dob = SOURCE.dob, 
             ghdstartdate = SOURCE.ghdstartdate, 
             yearsexperience = SOURCE.yearsexperience, 
             classification = SOURCE.classification 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
  INSERT (psnid, 
          servicegroup, 
          discipline, 
          dob, 
          ghdstartdate, 
          yearsexperience, 
          classification) 
  VALUES ('GC91', 
          '41B001', 
          'IT', 
          '1967-09-28', 
          '2008-12-15', 
          '11 to 20 years', 
          'Admin Officer 1')
```

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit dense but, how does MERGE fix this issue? And where is the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your SQL to this:

```
UPDATE StaffDetail SET PsnID = 'GC91',ServiceGroup = '41B001',Discipline = 'IT',DOB = '1967-09-28',GHDStartDate = '2008-12-15',YearsExperience = '11 to 20 years',Classification = 'Admin Officer 1' WHERE PsnID = 'GC91';

INSERT INTO StaffDetail (PsnID,ServiceGroup,Discipline,DOB,GHDStartDate,YearsExperience,Classification) 
SELECT 'GC91','41B001','IT','1967-09-28','2008-12-15','11 to 20 years','Admin Officer 1'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM StaffDetail WHERE PsnID = 'GC91')
```

Answer (score 0):

can you put the above code as Stored Procedure definition and pass thru using con.prepareStatement ?

Answer (score 0):

A late update, in case others find my findings useful...

I have had this problem a lot recently.  Re-architeching the query to either use CTE or Table Variables has often resolved it, but believe that ultimately, as noted at http://computer-aaaargh.blogspot.co.za/2012/12/weird-cause-of-msg-3989-new-request-is.html , it has to do with the underlying data.  Look at your joins and try and change what you are fetching back from the underlying data - in this case only the one statement (Try SELECT 1 FROM StaffDetail WHERE PsnID = 'GC91') or use another script in the exist just as a form of elimination.